# Can't pass values in SQL Query: incomplete format

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I try to create a function that updates column value in the DB table.

```
if DoesKeyExist(row['campaign_id'], table, cur):
     query = 'UPDATE campaigns_table SET campaign_name = %s WHERE campaign_id = s%'
     data = (row['campaign_name'], row['campaign_id'],)
     cur.execute(query, data)
```

Here i get "Value error: incomplete format"
What i do wrong?
Help please.

Comment: `%s` instead of `s%`? on line 2 very end

Comment: yeeeeeeeaaaaah......i'm blind probably. I couldn't find error for nearly an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here `campaign_id = s%'`

```
if DoesKeyExist(row['campaign_id'], table, cur):
     query = 'UPDATE campaigns_table SET campaign_name = %s WHERE campaign_id = %s'
     data = (row['campaign_name'], row['campaign_id'],)
     cur.execute(query, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a typo I think. It should be `...campaign_id = %s` instead of `..campign_id = s%`